# Reorganizing MySQL table to multiple rows by timestamp

Tags: mysql, group-by

OK MySQL Wizards:

I have a table of position data from multiple probes defined as follows:

```
+----------+----------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field    | Type     | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+----------+----------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| time     | datetime | NO   |     | NULL    |       | 
| probe_id | char(3)  | NO   |     | NULL    |       | 
| position | float    | NO   |     | NULL    |       | 
+----------+----------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

A simple select outputs something like this:

```
+---------------------+----------+----------+
| time                | probe_id | position |
+---------------------+----------+----------+
| 2010-05-05 14:16:42 | 00A      |   0.0045 | 
| 2010-05-05 14:16:42 | 00B      |   0.0005 | 
| 2010-05-05 14:16:42 | 00C      |    0.002 | 
| 2010-05-05 14:16:42 | 01A      |        0 | 
| 2010-05-05 14:16:42 | 01B      |    0.001 | 
| 2010-05-05 14:16:42 | 01C      |   0.0025 | 
| 2010-05-05 14:16:43 | 00A      |   0.0045 | 
| 2010-05-05 14:16:43 | 00B      |   0.0005 | 
| 2010-05-05 14:16:43 | 00C      |    0.002 | 
| 2010-05-05 14:16:43 | 01A      |        0 | 
|          .          |  .       |      .   |
|          .          |  .       |      .   |
|          .          |  .       |      .   |
+---------------------+----------+----------+
```

However, I'd like to output something like this:

```
+---------------------+--------+--------+-------+-----+-------+--------+
| time                | 00A    | 00B    | 00C   | 01A | 01B   | 01C    |
+---------------------+--------+--------+-------+-----+-------+--------+
| 2010-05-05 14:16:42 | 0.0045 | 0.0005 | 0.002 | 0   | 0.001 | 0.0025 |
| 2010-05-05 14:16:43 | 0.0045 | 0.0005 | 0.002 | 0   | 0.001 | 0.0025 |
| 2010-05-05 14:16:44 | 0.0045 | 0.0005 | 0.002 | 0   | 0.001 | 0.0025 |
| 2010-05-05 14:16:45 | 0.0045 | 0.0005 | 0.002 | 0   | 0.001 | 0.0025 |
| 2010-05-05 14:16:46 | 0.0045 | 0.0005 | 0.002 | 0   | 0.001 | 0.0025 |
| 2010-05-05 14:16:47 | 0.0045 | 0.0005 | 0.002 | 0   | 0.001 | 0.0025 |
|          .          |    .   |    .   |   .   | .   |   .   |    .   |
|          .          |    .   |    .   |   .   | .   |   .   |    .   |
|          .          |    .   |    .   |   .   | .   |   .   |    .   |
+---------------------+--------+--------+-------+-----+-------+--------+
```

Ideally, the different probe position columns are dynamically generated based on data in the table. Is this possible, or am I pulling my hair out for nothing?

I've tried GROUP BY time with GROUP_CONCAT that roughly gets the data out, but I can't separate that output into probe_id columns.

```
mysql> SELECT time, GROUP_CONCAT(probe_id), GROUP_CONCAT(position) FROM MG41 GROUP BY time LIMIT 10;
+---------------------+-------------------------+------------------------------------+
| time                | GROUP_CONCAT(probe_id)  | GROUP_CONCAT(position)             |
+---------------------+-------------------------+------------------------------------+
| 2010-05-05 14:16:42 | 00A,00B,00C,01A,01B,01C | 0.0045,0.0005,0.002,0,0.001,0.0025 | 
| 2010-05-05 14:16:43 | 01C,01B,01A,00C,00B,00A | 0.0025,0.001,0,0.002,0.0005,0.0045 | 
| 2010-05-05 14:16:44 | 01C,01B,01A,00C,00B,00A | 0.0025,0.001,0,0.002,0.0005,0.0045 | 
| 2010-05-05 14:16:45 | 01C,01B,01A,00C,00B,00A | 0.0025,0.001,0,0.002,0.0005,0.0045 | 
| 2010-05-05 14:16:46 | 01C,01B,01A,00C,00B,00A | 0.0025,0.001,0,0.002,0.0005,0.0045 | 
| 2010-05-05 14:16:47 | 01C,01B,01A,00C,00B,00A | 0.0025,0.001,0,0.002,0.0005,0.0045 | 
| 2010-05-05 14:16:48 | 01C,01B,01A,00C,00B,00A | 0.0025,0.001,0,0.002,0.0005,0.0045 | 
| 2010-05-05 14:16:49 | 01C,01B,01A,00C,00B,00A | 0.0025,0.001,0,0.002,0.0005,0.0045 | 
| 2010-05-05 14:16:50 | 01C,01B,01A,00C,00B,00A | 0.0025,0.001,0,0.002,0.0005,0.0045 | 
| 2010-05-05 14:16:51 | 01C,01B,01A,00C,00B,00A | 0.0025,0.001,0,0.002,0.0005,0.0045 | 
+---------------------+-------------------------+------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT
    time,
    SUM(CASE WHEN probe_id = '00A' THEN position ELSE 0 END) `00A`,
    SUM(CASE WHEN probe_id = '00B' THEN position ELSE 0 END) `00B`,
    SUM(CASE WHEN probe_id = '00C' THEN position ELSE 0 END) `00C`,
    SUM(CASE WHEN probe_id = '01A' THEN position ELSE 0 END) `01A`,
    SUM(CASE WHEN probe_id = '01B' THEN position ELSE 0 END) `01B`,
    SUM(CASE WHEN probe_id = '01C' THEN position ELSE 0 END) `01C`
FROM MG41
GROUP BY time LIMIT 10;
```

Comment: Thanks Mark. I added ROUND(x,4) to get rid of the extra decimal places from SUM.

Answer (score 1):

To have a dynamic number of rows, you will need a dynamically generated query. (If you know in advance the probe_ids, then you can juse use a static query.)

The general form will be

```
    SELECT time, P00A, P00B, ... P03B, etc..
    FROM 
       (SELECT time FROM MG41 GROUP BY time) allTimes
    INNER JOIN 
        (SELECT time, position AS P00A from MG41 WHERE probe_id='00A') pt00A 
        ON pt00A.time=allTimes.time   
   INNER JOIN 
        (SELECT time, position AS P00B from MG41 WHERE probe_id='00B') pt00B 
        ON pt00B.time=allTimes.time

etc...
```

You then build out the INNER JOINs and the SELECTed rows for all the different probes.